# SQL SELECT DISTINCT newest line from group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a current query which returns all the values from the parameters queried.

However it returns older values when i only want the **latest** line for each to show, I have had a go at using `max()` and `DISTINCT` but i cannot get the output i want

**Current Code**

```
SELECT 
IME.TP AS [Time],
IU.FS07 AS [LID], 
IU.I AS [LNum],
IME.TPL AS [Location],
(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN IME.TPL = 'Y' 
        THEN 'GTG' 
        ELSE 
            (SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN IME.TPL = 'V' 
                    THEN 'WAIT' 
                    ELSE 'WAIT' 
                    END) 
        END) AS [Go To]

FROM
IU 
INNER JOIN IUFV ON IU.G = IUFV.UG
INNER JOIN IME ON IUFV.G = IME.UFVG
```

**Current Output**

```
 ________________________________________________________________
|Time                       LID     LNum        Location    Go To|
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|2012-07-08 10:54:57.837    CCC     CCC111      V           WAIT |
|2012-07-08 12:15:07.000    CCC     CCC111      Y           GTG  |
|2012-07-17 06:58:33.417    CCC     CCC111      T           WAIT |
|2012-08-09 03:51:20.750    BBB     BBB222      Y           GTG  |
|2012-08-09 04:06:13.473    BBB     BBB222      Y           GTG  |
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

**Desired Output**

```
 ________________________________________________________________
|Time                       LID     LNum        Location    Go To|
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|2012-07-17 06:58:33.417    CCC     CCC111      T           WAIT |
|2012-08-09 04:06:13.473    BBB     BBB222      Y           GTG  |
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Comment: Knowing the table structure fro IME would help.  You need to to generate a set of data which consists of the max times grouped by the related value LID or whatever, maybe it's IUFV.G, I can't tell.  Then join to that set on time, it will exclude the unwanted records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
IME.TP AS [Time],
IU.FS07 AS [LID], 
IU.I AS [LNum],
IME.TPL AS [Location],
(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN IME.TPL = 'Y' 
        THEN 'GTG' 
        ELSE 'WAIT'
        END) AS [Go To]

FROM
IU 
INNER JOIN IUFV ON IU.G = IUFV.UG
INNER JOIN IME ON IUFV.G = IME.UFVG
INNER JOIN (Select Max(time) MTime, UFVG from IME
GROUP BY UFVG) B
 on B.UFVG=IUFV.G
 and B.MTime = IME.Time
```

Without a Deeper dive, I'm not sure if I could eliminate the additional join and just get the results from IME in the first place. but the need for TPL may necessitate the separate join

```
SELECT 
IME.TP AS [Time],
IU.FS07 AS [LID], 
IU.I AS [LNum],
IME.TPL AS [Location],
(SELECT CASE 
        WHEN IME.TPL = 'Y' 
        THEN 'GTG' 
        ELSE 'WAIT'
        END) AS [Go To]

FROM
IU 
INNER JOIN IUFV ON IU.G = IUFV.UG
INNER JOIN (Select Max(time) MTime, UFVG from IME
GROUP BY UFVG) B
 on B.UFVG=IUFV.G
 and B.MTime = IME.Time
```

Comment: First code works for the LID CCC but not the BBB, the BBB lines still have multiple values

Comment: What does `Select Max(time) MTime, UFVG from IME
GROUP BY UFVG` return?  It should be max time for for each unique UFVG.  Does LID CCC have multiple UFVGs?

Comment: Instead of having the UFVG as the unique identifier could i use the LNUM (IU.I) as this is also a unique value

Comment: To really Help I need to understand the relationships and table structures better for all the tablesIU, IUFV (IU.G = IUFV.UG), and IME (IUFV.G = IME.UFVG?)  IME seems to join to IUFV on UFVG.  Does IME also have LNUM

Comment: LNUM (IU.I) is only in the table IU

Comment: Yep, back to needing to know all table structures and relations.

Comment: IU is linked to IUFV by IU.G = IUFV.UG & 
IME is linked to IUFV by IUFV.G = IME.UFVG

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic approach. I'm assuming you never have duplicate timestamps within a group.

```
select *
from T
    inner join (select GrpId, max(TimeStmp) from T group by GrpId) as MaxT
        on MaxT.GrpId = T.GrpId and T.TimeStmp = MaxT.TimeStmp
```